# Exception - Layout measurement override of element 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid' should not return NaN values as its DesiredSize

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, uielement, measure

I am getting an exception,

> Layout measurement override of element 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid'
>   should not return NaN values as its DesiredSize.

StackTrace :

> at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Canvas.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Canvas.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)    at
>   System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()    at
>   System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
>   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
>   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object
>   resizedCompositionTarget)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object
>   resizedCompositionTarget)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
>   Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

How to solve this? Help me please...

Comment: How about providing some more details?

Comment: Please post the code that is throwing the exception.

Comment: INF, IND and NAN values occur when your math operations are not defined or yield  results that can not be represented in the floating point ranges, such as square rooting -1, dividing by 0 etc.. see http://www.johndcook.com/blog/ieee_exceptions_in_cpp/

Answer (score 0):

You may need to bound the Grid size.  Give it a max and min.

I got a similar error:

"Layout measurement override of element 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid' should not return PositiveInfinity as its DesiredSize, even if Infinity is passed in as available size."

When I put a grid in a ScrollViewer.  Setting a max height resolved this.